# Stagefright: OMX Subsystem in Stagefright and OMX Core are running in which process context

Tags: stagefright, openmax

I am facing some issues with Stagefright command line utility where I am unable to understand if the `OMX` subsystem (`OMX`, `OMXMaster`) in `Stagefright` and `OMX` core are running in the current application's process or different process. Which part of the code in `Stagefright` explains the communication between `OMXCodec` and `OMX` subsystem. There is no much information in google. I kindly request the readers to give explanation on these concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `AwesomePlayer` object is created, [`mClient.connect`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#208) is called which basically invokes the `OMXClient`'s connect method.

In the implementation `OMXClient::connect`, one can observe that `media.player` service is retrieved through with `mOMX` is initialized as can be observed from [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXClient.cpp#382).

`MediaPlayerService` is [registered through the instantiation](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.cpp#206) invoked by `MediaServer` as [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/mediaserver/main_mediaserver.cpp#128).

In other words, `OMX` native implementation is running in `MediaServer` process where as the proxy is running in the caller's context which could be the shell in case of `Stagefright` command line utility.

When a new component is allocated, the component could be a `SoftOMXComponent` or a `HW` accelerated component. The `SoftOMXComponent` is created in the caller's context, whereas the `HW` accelerated component is created in `MediaServer`. This is managed through 2 variables `mLocalOMX` and `mRemoteOMX` as [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXClient.cpp#200).